# Running an ICC analysis

Tags: r, icc, coefficients

Cannot run an ICC analysis in R

I have loaded my data from excel spreadsheet and have tried the following:
ICC(CMI)

I have removed my row names. I am not sure if I need to convert my columns or use a difference approach. I have loaded the Psych package.

This is my code: `ICC(Test)`
This is what comes back:

> Error in stack.data.frame(x) : no vector columns were selected

Not sure of what this means or how to fix this? Thanks in advance for any help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with a dataset. I suggest you try:

> ICC(as.matrix(Test))

. This worked for me. Otherwise, type help(ICC) and check the example and compare the procedure used there compared to your data.

Good luck!